# schtasks creates remote task but gives "Access is denied"

Tags: windows-task-scheduler

I'm running schtasks to create a task in a remote machine.

```
    schtasks /create /SC dayly /TN logcleaner /TR c:\logcleaner.cmd /ST 00:00 /S 10.0.0.1 /RU uname /RP passwd
```

The task gets created in the remote system, but It cnt be run.
If i go to the task itself and set the password in the properties, it runs ok.

Any idea how to get it working in one shoot on command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to go around this a little.
So, to make it work, I create an exe in the remote host and then run it with wmic. Example:

```
    set "EXEC=schtasks /Create /SC DAILY /TN taskname /TR script.cmd /ST 02:30 /S 10.0.0.1 /RU SYSTEM"
    echo !EXEC! > \\10.0.0.1\c$\script.cmd
    WMIC /node:10.0.0.1 /user:username /password:password process call create "script.exe /c \\10.0.0.1\c$\script.cmd"
```